# How to Add & Style Phantom CSS Borders to an HTML element using Pseudo Selectors ::before and ::after

Tags: html, css, layout, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I would like to have two borders, one left and one right set and realtive to `1em` inside the `<nav>` element.

I succeeded by adding an extra HTML element which I then styled, however I find that not an elegant solution and want to achieve this in pure CSS using just `::before` and `::after`.

Undesired:

```
<nav>
  <div style="lines"></div>
  Content
<nav>
```

Desired:

```
<nav>
  Content
<nav>
```

I do Not want to add any extra HTML elements. I want the two borders placed `1em` relative to the inside of the lightblue `<nav>` box.

My solution works partially, but for some reason the borders are "connected" relative to the entire HTML page, and not to the nav element.

What have I overlooked?

[image]

```css
html {background: #EEE; margin: 10em}

body {background: #DDD; margin: 0 auto;}

nav{background: lightblue; height: 80vh; padding: 1em;}


nav::before, nav::after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
    height: 80vh;
    border-right: 2px solid #EEE;
    border-left: 2px solid #AAA;
}


nav::before{left: 1em; }
nav::after{right: 1em; border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
Test
Test
Test
</nav>
```

Comment: Maybe your pseudolements have position: absolute but you forgot to add position: relative to the element? It's hard to guess without seeing the actual code.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, updated question and added snippet. When I replace `absolute` with `relative`, then the layout breaks and the borders are placed right after the text, which is Not what I want, I want the border to be set at `1em` relative to the light blue box, on the inside.

Comment: *I want the border to be set at 1em relative to the light blue box, on the inside.* this is exactly the result. if you need to add more space between the borders and the text then increase the padding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pseudolements have `position: absolute` but you forgot to add `position: relative` to the `nav` element.

An element with `position: absolute` is positioned according to the first positioned ancestor (e.g with `position: relative`) or, if missing, to the root element

```css
  html {background: #EEE; margin: 10em}

  body {background: #DDD; margin: 0 auto;}

  nav{
    background: lightblue; 
    height: 80vh; 
    padding: 1em 2em; 
    position: relative;
  }

  nav::before, nav::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
      height: 80vh;
      border-right: 2px solid #EEE;
      border-left: 2px solid #AAA;
  }


  nav::before{left: 1em; }
  nav::after{right: 1em; border-bottom: none; }
```

```html
<nav>
Test
Test
Test
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks! This solves it. Can you please explain in one or two sentences in your answer WHY it is necessary to add `relative` to the parent html element?